# Javascript: Unable to access public prop from private method

Tags: javascript

Quick question.

I've been using jQuery (in moderation) for a long time, but I've never really had much experience with "classes" (used loosely).

Here is my test "class", available at http://jsfiddle.net/TxUs2/.

```
function MyClass(prop) {
    this.prop = prop;

    var init = function()
    {
        alert(this.prop);
    }

    init();
}

var myClass = new MyClass();
```

I want the init() method to be private. Please could someone briefly explain why I am unable to access a public property from a private method?

I'm assuming it has something to do with 'this' essentially pointing to the method itself from within the method, and not the containing function (or "class"). How do I get around this?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: Many thanks for all of your input. All answers were excellent. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you invoke `init` it's being called with no context and therefore `this` does not refer to an instance of `MyClass`. You can solve this by saving a reference to `this` in the constructor, calling `init` in the context of `this` or binding `init` to `this`:

- Saving a reference to `this`:

  ```
  function MyClass(prop) {
      this.prop = prop;

      var that = this;
      var init = function() {
          alert(that.prop);
      }

      init();
  }
  ```
- Calling `init` in the context of `this`:

  ```
  init.call(this);
  ```
- Binding `init` to `this` (which makes every call behave like `init.call(this)`):

  ```
  var init = function () {
      alert(this.prop);
  }.bind(this);

  init();
  ```

Comment: Note that [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is a newer JavaScript feature, so older browsers like IE8 do not support it.

Comment: There's a handy polyfill on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 3):

In your current code, `init()` is a "free" function. If you call it naturally, within its body `this` will be set to the global object (or to `undefined` in strict mode).

You could make it a method by writing:

```
this.init = function() {
    alert(this.prop);
};

this.init();
```

Or you could use [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to provide the context at call-time:

```
var init = function() {
    alert(this.prop);
};

init.call(this);
```